# Insert into 2 tables one being Junction

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a web-form that asks for company information and has a checkbox list of categories that any "listing" can be a part off similar to yellow pages.

I'm using a Junction table to be able to have 1 listing be categorized more than 1 time.

I have my insert statement into my principal table working fine. I'm running into a bit of trouble inserting X amount of times depending on how many categories are selected into my Junction Table.

```
INSERT INTO BND_Listing
(Company,Doors,Address,Address2,etc...)
VALUES
('[Company]','[Doors]','[Address]','[Address2]',etc...)
```

In addition to the above I can run another query but how can I have it fire X amount of times depending on categories selected? Is this even possible? Similarly is this possible for an UPDATE statement?

Comment: how are you inserting into your principal table? server side executing dynamic queries or calling stored proc with params? Assuming company information goes in your principal table, giving you the id of new record, use it with categories ids from webpage to fill junction table.

Comment: Server side executing dynamic queries. I could also call a stored proc just don't know how to create one.

Comment: Ok, so in your webpage post back, you need to retrieve category names or ids, depending on how your checkboxes are laid out. Loop through checked checkboxes, get category id or name (usable provided they are unique) and fire two dynamic insert queries perhaps in a transaction scope (check TransactionScope Class), one for company (get company id) and other for categories junction table (with category id and company id).

Comment: for stored proc you can check [Update Junction table in many-to-many relationship](https://forums.asp.net/post/2960746.aspx). Although in your case it's 1:N, but in principle it is same thing.

Comment: @ukhardy thank you for the input i'll read up about TransactionScope Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading a bit around the net I found the following possible solution and wanted to get you're guy's input.

Do you think this could work?

use a While Loop into the Run Sql Action, for example:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

WHILE @cnt < 3
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Junction (categories)
Values ('[Category]') 
SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;
```